# Unable to read csv file in jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, operating-system, opencsv, read.csv

I was trying to read csv file in jupyter notebook but it showed error of filenotfound. Then I tried to check whether my file is present then it shoewd false as output. But I have checked the file location in my files explorer and the csv file is present .How should I read the file?

```
import os
os.path.isfile(r'C:\Users\Ritesh\Downloads\Data\Amazon_Products.csv')
```

[Screenshot of code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn8KP.png)

Comment: Since you tagged this with panda, I assume u want to gernerate a data-frame. why not 
`import pandas as pd` and them `pd.read_csv` ..... I suggest reading  the docs for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('your-filepath')
```

you could also try to move the file into your project directory so that it is in the same folder as the .ipynb